# change fb:like to div element, possible?

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-fbml

Can this be replacd into `<div class="facebook...`  , i do not want to use facebook prefix. i want to use div tag as it is more standard html

```
<fb:like layout="box_count" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

**Side note:**

*fb:like* is actually standard html in a way. The *fb:* is a namespace and the like is an element in the *fb* namespace. This is just the same as a *div* being and element in the default html namespace. So you are actually using standard html.

You'll see the namespace declared in the html tag when you visit the page with the like button. The fb namespace appears along side the default html namespace:

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" ... />`